# Xamarin Android How to put multiple control in 1 line

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Right now I'm developing mobile App with Xamarin, I want to know how to put multiple controls in one line for example, how would I put two equal sized button in one line?

I tried to dragged them into one line but it won't work. I'm guessing there is something call divider or something else. Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Xamarin specific question. You need to look into the Android documentation to see how you can make proper layouts.

In your case you want two equally sized controls in one view. You can do that with something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The android:layout_weight="2" will distribute the size of the 2 buttons over the view.

Answer (score 1):

For those who prefer Code behind:

```
Button Button1 = new Button { Text = " Button 1" };
Button Button2 = new Button { Text = " Button 2" };
StackLayout myStackLayout = new StackLayout {
    Children = {
        Button1,
        Button2
    },
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, 
};
```

For more info check the following link 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39101/put-two-buttons-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Cross Platform:

Android,IOS and UWP

Use this Code...

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Next" Command="{Binding NextQuestion}" BackgroundColor="DimGray" TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="End to Exam" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" TextColor="Black"/>
            </StackLayout>
```